# How to Insert PHP Code in FSE Theme Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add some php code in single.html inside FSE theme wordpress like twentytwentythree, twentytwentytwo and etc. I have try change the extension for single.html to single.php but when i do that the wordpress use index.html for single page instead of use single.php. I just know how to insert php code in html is change the extension. Please help me..

this is single.html file

```
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"header","tagName":"header"} /-->

<!-- wp:group {"tagName":"main"} -->

<main class="wp-block-group"><!-- wp:group {"layout":{"inherit":true}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group">
    <!-- wp:post-title {"level":1,"align":"wide","style":{"spacing":{"margin":{"bottom":"var(--wp--custom--spacing--medium, 6rem)"}}}} /-->

    <!-- wp:post-featured-image {"align":"wide","style":{"spacing":{"margin":{"bottom":"var(--wp--custom--spacing--medium, 6rem)"}}}} /-->

    <!-- wp:separator {"align":"wide","className":"is-style-wide"} -->
    <hr class="wp-block-separator alignwide is-style-wide" />
    <!-- /wp:separator -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->

<!-- wp:spacer {"height":32} -->
<div style="height:32px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>
<!-- /wp:spacer -->

<!-- wp:post-content {"layout":{"inherit":true}} /-->


<!-- wp:spacer {"height":32} -->
<div style="height:32px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>
<!-- /wp:spacer -->

<!-- wp:group {"layout":{"inherit":true}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"flex"}} -->
    <div class="wp-block-group">
        <!-- wp:post-date {"format":"F j, Y","style":{"typography":{"fontStyle":"italic","fontWeight":"400"}},"fontSize":"small"} /-->

        <!-- wp:post-author {"showAvatar":false,"fontSize":"small"} /-->

        <!-- wp:post-terms {"term":"category","fontSize":"small"} /-->

        <!-- wp:post-terms {"term":"post_tag","fontSize":"small"} /-->
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:group -->

    <!-- wp:spacer {"height":32} -->
    <div style="height:32px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>
    <!-- /wp:spacer -->

    <!-- wp:separator {"className":"is-style-wide"} -->
    <hr class="wp-block-separator is-style-wide" />
    <!-- /wp:separator -->

    <!-- wp:post-comments /-->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
</main>
<!-- /wp:group -->
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"footer","tagName":"footer"} /-->
```

I just want i can insert and running the php code inside the single.html file.

Comment: Change the extension is not the way to insert php code. By changing the extension, you are changing the name of the file, and that's why Wordpress starts using index.html, because simple.html wasn't found.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have change to real code

Comment: @spaniard Yes i know and i have tried if change the extension is not the solution. So I asked here hoping to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding the way to do this is create a pattern php file and then use that pattern in your hmtl template.